# built excel function makes error 1004 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need to use statistic function in my VBA code but unfortunately error 1004 appears when I try to use built excel function.

My code:

```
Dim pValue() As Double
ReDim pValue(number - 1) 
For i = 0 To number - 1
    pValue(i) = WorksheetFunction.T_Inv_2T(Abs(StatT(i)), 17)
Next
```

And StatT Array consists of elements [10,82;-9,12;3,19]

Please help.

Comment: Nope, nothing change :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probability must be between 0 and 1:

```
    pValue(i) = WorksheetFunction.T_Inv_2T(Abs(StatT(i) * 0.01), 17)
```

Comment: My god... I used wrong function... Anyway your answer solve the problem. Thank You :)